# jQuery and Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it smart to use jQuery as a JavaScript library in Chrome Extensions? jQuery and other DOM libraries are intended to hide the differences between browsers, and since I'm targeting Chrome only, should I use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no reasons to not use jQuery on one of your extension pages (background, popup, options etc). You should always use a local jQuery copy though, not load a remotely hosted one through http.

I would advise against injecting jQuery as a content script though, if possible. If all you need is some simple selector or event listener, injecting around 100kb of js code on each page visit is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: As content scripts would load jQuery from local disk and injection defaults to `document_idle` (optimized for page speed) I think it would be okay to load frequently. If you are using the run_at overrides for any other point of injection I would agree that avoiding unnecessary loads is important.

Comment: @mrtsherman When someone has 20 extensions installed that try to inject jquery on each page load in every tab, it would be noticeable.

Comment: +1 - That is a very good point. No being lazy.

Comment: Pure JS has this advantage. You get to write smaller code (in size) for smaller applications.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree; there are lots of good reasons not to use jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

I use it for my Chrome extensions and I think it is very smart. jQuery is more than just hiding differences. It is full of features that allow you to code faster and more robustly. There are tons of extensions that allow you to extend your scripts. I think you would be hurting yourself by *not* using it!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to coding faster and "Not reinventing the wheel (unnecessarily)" -- there may come a time when you need to work on something besides Chrome extensions.

jQuery makes it easier for you to reuse that effort on other platforms or in different circumstances.

Finally, by using a standard library, others will, more easily, be able to: help with, improve, or just plain trust, the code. (It won't be just yours, forever, if it's good.)

Comment: But jQuery is still only for the web. Javascript exists on server-side also.

Answer (score -1):

**No, you should not use jQuery in Chrome extensions.**

jQuery is fairly large and the vast majority of it is support for other browsers, something you just don't have to care about in an extension.

For instance you shouldn't need the Sizzle engine at all (use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)), though that's really valuable in IE6-8. You shouldn't need standardised event handlers as you won't be supporting IE or Opera at all (use [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)). You shouldn't need [jQuery's deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) implementation when [Chrome supports Promise natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You don't need [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) when you have [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). There are [lots more](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

In addition, jQuery doesn't support a lot of modern features, for instance you cannot use [passive event handlers](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871) or load scripts asynchronously (it [doesn't even support `defer`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3271)).

As the current selected answer also points out: jQuery is expensive to inject. It's worth optimising down to exactly what you need with minimal code.

As a general rule with any toolkit extension (jQuery, Underscore, etc) always start without them and only bring them in if you find you need them. If you do find that you need a framework consider more modern ones that leverage new functionality (that you can rely on being in Chrome) rather than ones designed to standardise code between browsers. Consider exactly what it is that you *need* from a framework - if it's just that you know and like jQuery then fine (familiarity can be a justification if there's a high cost for you/your team learning new things) but you should be aware of the related injection and execution cost in that decision.

jQuery is an exceptionally good toolkit with widespread support, it just isn't the *right* tool for Chrome-only extensions.